# Macro to Turn on and off properties not quite working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a case statement in my macro I think this is the part I am implementing incorrectly `Select Case Reset`

I know my macro is not working becouse if I use it on a live macro there is screen updating going on

Any insight is appreciated

Thank you

```
Sub Test()
goFast False

 Code

goFast True
End Sub
```

Edit: 6/10/14 update code to reflect improvement from comments

```
Sub goFast(Optional what As Boolean = False)
' Set various application properties.
    Select Case what

        Case False
          With Application
               .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
               .ScreenUpdating = False
               .EnableEvents = False
          End With

       Case True
         With Application
              .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
              .ScreenUpdating = True
              .EnableEvents = True
         End With
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I've tested this code and it works exactly as I expected. No screenupdating at all. Note: If you are stepping through the code in break mode, you **will** observe screenupdating even when set to False.

Comment: `Reset` is a reserved keyword in VBA; not a good idea to use this as a variable name...

Comment: Jean-Francois Corbett, I took your advice and changed `reset` to a different word, I updated the code to reflect this, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would send a comment, but no rep to do that so.. Have you checked that you refer to correct Sub? It seems you have goFast instead GoFast in your test Sub... Case sensitivity...

Comment: This can't possibly be the reason. VBA is not case sensitive. The OP must have done something else that fixed his issue, perhaps inadvertently.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett these are cases where vba acts like it's case sensitive. For instance calling a sub from another module works like this for some reason..